# How do I wait on a function to return to a global variable before continuing the script?

Tags: javascript

This is my function and I am wondering how I would go about waiting on the global variable so I could then use the list in another function. I know this isn't the best practice in javascript but not understanding how I would wait on it is bothering me

```js
function load_csv_async(){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        const fileInput = document.querySelector('input');
        fileInput.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
            const input = event.target; 
            const reader = new FileReader(); 
            reader.onload = () => {
                list = reader.result.split(/\r?\n/);
                console.log(list)
            };
            reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
        }) 
    });
}

const check = load_csv_async().catch((error) => {
console.log(error)});
console.log(check);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<input type="file" name="inputfile" id="inputfile">
```

Comment: Just don't use a global variable. Use `load_csv_async().then(check => anotherFunction(check))`

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understood your question, you want the result of the csv upload to be handled by another function call. For this you do not need to wrap it inside a promise or async function, you can simply structure your program to call the functions inside the event handler:

```js
fileInput.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
            const input = event.target; 
            const reader = new FileReader(); 
            reader.onload = () => {
                list = reader.result.split(/\r?\n/);
                console.log(list)
            };
            
            // if you want to have this as global variable just put it outside the Event Listener
            let result = reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
            someOtherFunction(result)
            
}) 

function someOtherFunction(param) {
  console.log(param)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<input type="file" name="inputfile" id="inputfile">
```

Hint: If you use promise for anything: you have to call `resolve` on result and `reject` on error in order to handle it properly:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    result = SomeFunctionToGetYourResult();
    if (result=="SomeTargetValue") {
        // Resolve if result is as intended
        resolve(result)
    } else {
        // Reject if your call was unsuccesfull.
        reject(SomeError)
    }

})
```

Another option is to call an async function in javascript:

```
async function someAsyncFunc() {

  return someAsyncProcessedValue;

}

let global;

try {
  
  global = await someAsyncFunction();

} catch (error) {
   console.log(error)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to use promises and wrap the file reader with one. Your read function should invoke `resolve` when the file is loaded (and ought to invoke `reject` on error).

It also makes sense to tease apart triggering action and a generic async file reader that takes a file and returns a promise. Doing so will provide a natural place to get the contents, avoiding a global altogether...

```js
const fileInput = document.querySelector('input');
fileInput.addEventListener('change', async (event) => {
  try {
    const fn = event.target.files[0];
    const text = await load_csv_async(fn);
    // text was global, now it's in a functional scope where it belongs
    console.log(text);
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
 
async function load_csv_async(fn){
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader(); 
    reader.onload = () => {
      const list = reader.result.split(/\r?\n/);
      resolve(list);
    };
    reader.onerror = error => {
      reject(error)
    };
    reader.readAsText(fn);

  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<input type="file" name="inputfile" id="inputfile">
```